# Considerations for choosing the correct H1 tag for an e-commerce website

Tags: seo, ecommerce, title, amazon, ebay

I am working on an online marketplace which has different categories like Jobs, Cars, Real Estate, etc.

This question is about choosing the best title (`h1` tag) for the search results page. Most of the marketplace platforms show the search criteria and/or category as the page title:

**ebay (searching for the term laptop):**

[image]

**Gumtree (searching in Jobs category):**

[image]

**So that's what I have done for my own marketplace:**

[image]

**Question:**

I was speaking with an SEO consultant and he said having dynamic numbers in `h1` tag has negative effect on page SEO, because search engines don't see a consistent header. Is this true? Would it be better if I bring the numbers out of `h1` and put them in a `label` tag?

Comment: it will be more important for you to implement the correct semantic markup for the search results page, as well as for the site search box https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/sitelinks-searchbox#website

Answer (score 2):

### I don't think it *needs* to be an `<h1>`

First, to answer your question:

> ...having dynamic numbers in h1 tag has negative effect on page SEO, because search engines don't see a consistent header.

This is **subjective**.

From like 2001 to ~2008 there was a keyword ranking bonus with `<h1>` tags. This is because early Google depended on hints. So it was strategic to use exact match keywords in the headings and keep them consistent to hold that ranking. You only wanted a single `<h1>` to prevent confusion. Nowadays, whether you have 0 or 4, Google will not care because they don't need it to understand the page. A less mature search engine might.

---

> Would it be better if I bring the numbers out of h1 and put them in a label tag?

I would not get too hung up about this. You could make the whole thing a `<p>`, `<span>`, or whatever you like and this would not hinder your pages from ranking. Amazon, for example, doesn't even use an `<h1>` on its search result pages.

It seems excessive to me.

In your case, you have the number of results and words that describe what the results represent. If the number changes, that means that the content changed, but it doesn't change the topical relevance. You simply don't have the same amount of results whatever it is anymore.

In general, search engines are looking to understand *meaning*. So in your 2nd screenshot the part of the string that matters is "Jobs in Australia". Google will likely just ignore the numbers whether they're in the same tag or separate ones.

---

### What would I do?

You could use something other than an `<h1>` on your search result pages - it doesn't feel as appropriate as a heading.

What I mean is that I don't think that "34,000 Results for Gold Mens Watches" (for example) is the best use.

Displaying a larger heading that actually looks like a heading separately from the number of search results I would support.

```html
<header class="results-head">
    <h1>Gold Mens Watches</h1>
    <span>34,000 Results Found</span>
</header>
```

### Other Opportunities for `<h1>`

If you keep track of what users of your marketplace are searching for, we might want to create some **static pages to rank for popular searches** - those can have an optimized `<h1>` tag in a way that makes sense. This way users also don't have to search for it anymore...you're adding to your UX now as well.

For example we might have:

```html
<header>
    <h1>Popular Men's Nike Air-Max Running Shoes</h1>
    <!-- List all based on which sell the most -->
</header>
```

You can also use an `<h1>` on your **"view all"** pages. That would be appropriate too.

### Inspecting Element on Amazon After a Search for "iphone"

So it looks like Amazon *does* use an `<h1>` but the particular element in question is a `<span>` inside of it. So I stand corrected there, but I still hold that it does *not* need to be one.

[image: Screenshot showing no h1 on amazon]

### Google's John Mueller on `<h1>` Tags:

> “You can use H1 tags as often as you want on a page. There’s no limit, neither upper or lower bound. Your site is going to rank perfectly fine with no H1 tags or with five H1 tags.”

[Source](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/h1-headings-for-google/406720/)

Comment: thanks for your answer... I don't think excluding the `h1` tag is a good advice. Most of the e-commerce websites that I have seen use an `h1` tag for the Search Result title, including [amazon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfhzA.png)

Comment: It is your choice to take my advice or not. I was incorrect about Amazon is using an `<h1>`, it's a `<span>` inside an `<h1>`. Go ahead and do it. _I_ don't think it matters.  _I_ would still not use it for this.

Comment: When I use SEMRUSH to audit my website, it's very picky about H1 tag... it always complains when the H1 tags is not present on the page, or if there are more than one H1 tags on the same page... Do you have any reference to point us why you believe having an H1 tag is not required?

Comment: I added a reference. Audits from tools like SEMrush, Ahrefs, etc often will tell you things are an issue when they are not.

Comment: I also slightly modified my answer

Comment: Thanks for including the refence.